# npm knox signed url http

Tags: node.js, npm, knox-amazon-s3-client

I am using the nodejs npm package 'knox' to connect to amazon s3. And I would like to create a download url.

At the moment I use:

```
var expires = new Date();
expires.setMinutes(expires.getMinutes() + 30);
var url =  client.signedUrl('/test/obj.json', expires);
```

This generates HTTPS URLs that look like this:

```
HTTPS://......../test/obj.json......
```

Is it possible to get a http url?

```
HTTP://......./text/obj.json......
```

I want to show images on my homepage and they dont need to be TLS secured.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all familiar with Knox, but looking [at the code](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/blob/master/lib/client.js#L246), if you pass a `port` option to the `Client` constructor it will use `http` instead of `https`.

Comment: In the Knox documentation it says that when you turn the 'secure' flag to http or change the port (which makes the secure flag default to http ) the communication to the Amazon S3 is via HTTP, isn't this a security risk for my credentials?

Comment: @NilsZiehn if it would mean that *everything* is passed over HTTP, then it might not be the best thing to do.

Comment: Thats at least how I understand the Knox documentation.